# HADOOP and SQOOP working with a weird error

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, software-center

```
hdp@ubuntu:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version
bash: $/home/hdp/hadoop-2.6.4/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
hdp@ubuntu:~$ sqoop version 
/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop: line 79: dirname: command not found
/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop: line 81: basename: command not found
/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop: line 97: dirname: command not found
/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop: line 100: /home/hdp/configure-sqoop: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop: line 101: /home/hdp/$/home/hdp/hadoop-2.6.4/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop: line 101: exec: /home/hdp/$/home/hdp/hadoop-2.6.4/bin/hadoop: cannot execute: No such file or directory
hdp@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Hey, next time you post consider asking a question. This is just a statement - you have a weird error and then some error codes. Think about the quality of answer you want to receive for this issue, and then post a question with the same quality. This time please [edit] your question.

Comment: also if you edit your question and add lines 79,81,97 ,100 and 101 from `/usr/lib/sqoop//bin/sqoop` you may get some help

Answer (score 0):

If you `echo $HADOOP_HOME` you'll find that you made a typo in the path. This will output `$/home/hdp/hadoop-2.6.4/` which is nor a directory nor a file and bash was smart enough to answer.

To fix it just type this it Terminal

```
HADOOP_HOME=/home/hdp/hadoop-2.6.4/
export HADOOP_HOME
```